# Linux bash: Find and delete files older than 20 days in given file name format

Tags: linux, bash, find

I wanted to make a script, but somehow I don't get any further.

My files are stored in this layout:

/dir/to/files/*iobroker_YYYY_MM_DD-HH_MM_SS_backupiobroker.tar.gz*

Now I want to delete files older than 20 days, I tried this:

```
    find /dir/to/files -maxdepth 1 -name "iobroker_*" -type d -daystart -mtime +20 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I guess this is wrong since nothing is really deleted. Is there someone that can advise me on where my mistake is. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want to delete files why do you find only directories (`-type d`, twice)?

Comment: And note that using `rm -rf` is risky. Prefer `rm -f` when deleting files.

Comment: Deleting -type d fixed it. What is the "-type" for .tar.gz-files?  Why is rm -rf risky?

Comment: `type -f` (file) and/or  `-name "iobroker_*tar.gz"`

Comment: `-type f` if they are regular files, `-type f,l` if they can also be links and your are using GNU find, `\(-type f -o -type l\)` if they can also be links and your are not using GNU find. `rm -rf` is risky because if you get something wrong and pass it a directory it will be recursively (that what `-r` means) deleted with all its content. While with `rm -f` you will get an error if you try to delete a directory. Even when you are 100% sure, prefer `rm -f` when applicable. `rm -rf ~/Documents /foobar` is a disaster when you just want `rm -f ~/Documents/foobar`.

Comment: Also, if you are using GNU find, you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {}`. But only if you don't care too much about portability. The built-in delete option is significantly faster when you have lots of files.